How can I prevent newly added users from having their age increased in the same iteration in a linked list in C?
I'm creating a Linked List of Users where one of the field is int age;
The user can choose from several options (addUser, findUser, exit, etc.)
on each iteration of the while loop I want to increase the age of all the users by 5 but in my current implementation the newly added user is also affected although it needs to stay zero for the first time after it gets added to the linked list.
How can I solve that?
Here's my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER 1024
#define ADD_USER 1
#define ADD_USER 1
#define COMPLAINTS_AM 2
#define COMPLAINTS_EDA 3
#define COMPLAINTS_ASAFSUF 4
#define FIND_USER 5
#define PRINT_ALL_USERS 6
#define EXIT 7
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef enum Type
{
    Am = 0,
    Eda,
    Asafsuf
} Type;

typedef struct User
{
    int id;
    int counter;
    int age;
    char *name;
    Type type;
    struct User *next;
} User;

int main()
{
    int choice = 0;
    int isGoingOn = TRUE;

    User *head = NULL;

    while (isGoingOn)
    {
        printMenu();
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        increaseUsersAge(&head); // problematic (?!)
        RemoveUsersOverForty(&head);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case ADD_USER:
            addUser(&head);
            break;
        case COMPLAINTS_AM:
            printf("Ma Nishte?\n");
            addOneForAm(&head);
            break;
        case COMPLAINTS_EDA:
            printf("Lehamiteno berahav\n");
            addOneForEda(&head);
            break;
        case COMPLAINTS_ASAFSUF:
            printf("Mi Yaachileno Basar?\n");
            addOneForAsafsuf(&head);
            break;
        case FIND_USER:
            printUserById(&head);
            break;
        case PRINT_ALL_USERS:
            printAllUsers(head);
            break;
        case EXIT:
            isGoingOn = FALSE;
            break;
        default:
            printf("wrong choose please choose again.\n");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    freeMemory(&head);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

And this is my addUser function:
void addUser(User **head)
{
    // create new user
    User *newUser = malloc(sizeof(User));

    // get id from user
    printf("please insert id:\n");
    scanf("%d", &newUser->id);
    if (checkValidId(head, newUser->id) == FALSE)
    {
        printf("error\n");
        freeMemory(head);
        exit(1);
    }

    // get name from user
    printf("please insert name:\n");
    newUser->name = malloc(BUFFER * sizeof(char));
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", newUser->name);

    // get type from user
    printf("please insert type (Am - 0, Eda - 1, Asafsuf - 2):\n");
    scanf("%d", &newUser->type);

    newUser->counter = 0;
    newUser->age = 0;
    newUser->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = newUser;
        return;
    }

    // insert to end of linked list
    User *curr = *head;
    while (curr->next != NULL)
    {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = newUser;
}

and my increaseUsersAge function as well:
void increaseUsersAge(User **head)
{
    User *curr = *head;
    while (curr)
    {
        curr->age += 5;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}


By initialising it to -5?

Aside: this scanf(" %[^\n]s", newUser->name); is likely to be a mistake. There is format %s and there is format %[] which are quite distinct. AFAIK there is a beginners' book that teaches what you did, but %[] is not as subset of %s.

@WeatherVane I thought about that by it seems like it's not ideal. -5 doesn't truly represent an age doesn't it? but it'd work tho...

@WeatherVane about the scanf you probably right, I saw that online. I tried to use fgets but it seems like the previous scanfs messes it up...

Don't mix scanf with fgets and getchar until you are completely familar with the way all of them work. If you want to use fgets then get all inputs with it. If you needed scanf then use sscanf on the string.

Replace of addUser() with another function, say, createUser(), which will create the user node and return it. Hold it's reference in a local variable and pass it to another function, say, addUser(), which will add the newly created user to the list. Call addUser() just after increaseUsersAge().

@H.S. Thanks it works!

One way of doing it is to add a status field in the User structure which will keep the information whether the user is newly added user or not. Problem with this solution is that this field will eat-up some memory in all the user nodes of the list and once the user is no more a new user, this field is of no use.
Other solution could be to split the functionality of addUser() in two parts -

Part one: Only create user
Part two: Add user to the list

This solution provide the flexibility of adding the newly created user to the list after the calling increaseUsersAge() function.
Roughly, you can do:
Declare a local variable in main(), say:
User *lastAddedUser = NULL;

In case ADD_USER of while loop:
        case ADD_USER:
        lastAddedUser = createUser();
        if (lastAddedUser == NULL) {
            //print appropriate error message
            //free allocated memory and exit
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

In createUser(), only create the User node, add the information about user in that node and return it.
In while loop body of main():
while (isGoingOn)
{
    printMenu();
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    increaseUsersAge(&head); // problematic (?!)
    
    if (lastAddedUser) {
        addUserToList(&head, lastAddedUser);
        lastAddedUser = NULL;
    }
    
    RemoveUsersOverForty(&head);

    switch (choice)
    .....
    .....

In addUserToList() function, simply add the user whose reference passed as argument lastAddedUser -
void addUserToList(User **head, User * lastAddedUser) {
    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = lastAddedUser;
        return;
    }

    // insert to end of linked list
    User *curr = *head;

    while (curr->next != NULL) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    curr->next = lastAddedUser;
}

With this, the newly created user will not be affected by the call of increaseUsersAge() immediately after it.
